# How to send an integer via UDP scokets?( C language)

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

Client Side Code:

```
int main() { 
    int sockfd; 
    char buffer[MAXLINE]; 
    char *msg; 
    struct sockaddr_in     servaddr; 
  
    // Creating socket file descriptor 
    if ( (sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0 ) { 
        perror("socket creation failed"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 
  
    memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr)); 
      
    // Filling server information 
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT); 
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 
      
    int ch,n, len;
    printf("Enter '1' for Reversal of String.\n");
    printf("Enter '2' for number to binary conversion. \n");
    printf("Enter '3' for Echo server implementation. \n");
    scanf("%d",&ch);
    send(sockfd, int &ch, sizeof(ch),0);  
    close(sockfd); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Here, I want to send the variable **ch** to the server.
The above client program when compiled gives an error saying -

```
error: expected expression before ‘int’
send(sockfd, int &ch, sizeof(ch),0,0);

error: too few arguments to function ‘send’
send(sockfd, int &ch, sizeof(ch),0,0);
```

Also, how do **i** receive the sent integer in the server?

Comment: You're passing a lot of arguments to many functions, but nowhere else do you prefix the argument with a type. Why do you think you need to do it for that specific function argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't put type declarations in function calls, just put the expression. It should be:

```
send(sockfd, &ch, sizeof(ch), 0);
```

However, since you haven't called `connect()`, you need to use `sendto()` rather than `send()`, so you can specify the server address.

```
sendto(sockfd, &ch, sizeof(ch), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
```

On the server you use `recvfrom()` similarly.

```
nread = recvfrom(sockfd, &ch, sizeof(ch), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&clientaddr, &clientaddr_len);
```

Comment: "*However, you need to use `sendto()` rather than `send()`*" - unless you have called `connect()` beforehand.  You can `connect()` a UDP socket to a peer `sockaddr`, and then you can use `send()`/`recv()` instead of `sendto()`/`recvfrom()`.